# how to append item to a global list from within a procedure

Tags: python, global-variables, append

I get a syntax error when i do this:

```
p = []
def proc(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        C = i
        global p.append(C)
```

Comment: I think this question would be improved if you included the content of the title in the actual question.

Comment: List the specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just change it to the following:

```
def proc(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        C = i
        p.append(C)
```

The [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) statement can only be used at the very top of a function, and it is only necessary when you are assigning to the global variable.  If you are just modifying a mutable object it does not need to be used.

Here is an example of the correct usage:

```
n = 0
def set_n(i):
    global n
    n = i
```

Without the global statement in the above function this would just create a local variable in the function instead of modifying the value of the global variable.

Comment: "can only be used at the very top of a function" -- Isn't actually 100% true (at least not in my quick Cpython tests).  `def set_n(): b = 1; global n; n = i + b` works in your second example.  I think it's just that `n` must be declared as global *before* it gets parsed for some other reason, but that's a very minor nitpick.

Comment: Yes, the `global` just needs to appear before its referent is used (and only earns a warning, if not). But +1 anyway for mentioning the modifying-mutable-versus-assigning distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to print list directly instead convert into a string before printing,and as array is a member of class Student, you need to reference it using 'self'.

The following code works:

```
class Student:
    array = []
    def addstudent(self,studentName):
        print("New Student is added "+studentName)
        self.array.append(studentName)
        print(str(self.array))
    def removeStudent(self,studentName):
        print("Before Removing the Students from the  list are "+ str(self.array))
        self.array.remove(studentName)
        print("After Removing the students from the list are "+ str(self.array))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   studata = Student()
   studata.addstudent("Yogeeswar")
   studata.addstudent("Linga Amara")
   studata.addstudent("Mahanti")
   studata.removeStudent("Yogeeswar")
```